# Encrypted data in URLs

Tags: php, codeigniter, mcrypt

I am developing a PHP application to manage orders for a company.  To view an order the URL is currently `/orders/view/3502`.

I don't want the order ID number to appear in the URL, so I used CodeIgniter's encrypt library to encrypt the ID in the URL.  The URL (after encryption) looks like `/orders/view/AaffGdQQ`.

The problem I am having is sometimes the encrypted ID contains a forward slash or a plus sign, which don't work correctly when in a URL.  CodeIgniter reads the URL based on slashes, so, if the encrypted ID had a slash, it would read that as 2 variables, not one.  Also, plus signs are interpreted as spaces in URLs.

So, my question is, how can I encrypt the ID and be sure that the string does not contain a plus sign or a slash?

EDIT: I had an idea to see if the encrypted ID contained a slash or plus sign, and if it did, encrypt it again.  For some reason, every time the ID is encrypted, it's different, so this would work.

Comment: What's wrong with showing the order ID in the URL?

Comment: My boss doesn't want it there for 'security reasons'.

Comment: You should protect orders by cheking if user is actually authorized to view order, not by url obfuscation.

Comment: @newbie: Maybe they don't want the client to see low IDs ;)

Comment: @thejh then they should use something else as id for order in database

Comment: The system does check if you are authorized to view a certain page, but this is what my boss wants, so I can't change that.

Comment: If the order is just a four digit number (or six, it doesn't really matter), you could brute force that in a matter of minutes. I suggest using a 20 char. random string and what @newbie suggested.

Comment: I would show your boss that the order ID can be retrieved from the crypted data. That *might* convince him/her.

Comment: @Blender: Err... what? The point of crypted data sent to a client is that the client *can't* read it, just pass it back to the server.

Comment: The data is encrypted with a key, so it can only be decrypted by the server.

Comment: @Rocket if you add extra field to database and generate random unique string and use that as public id, then you don't have to worry about encryption

Comment: If I were you, I'd present it to your boss that it really isn't necessary. As long as the program checks that the user is authorised to view any page (and there really should do), encrypting the URL is redundant and useless.

Comment: Nathan MacInnes: Not necessarily.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also base64_encode(). That will also make it a lot longer and appear "more secure". Also adds a layer of obfuscation.

Comment: Yes, but you are already encrypting it with codeignighter :-) - this will remove those characters from the encrypted string that cant be used in a URL. Also obfuscates the encrypted string.

Comment: Oh, you meant base_64 the encrypted data?  That's a good idea.

Comment: base64_encode("$n(ryp7$)+/as89ijd&*"); returns KHJ5cDckKSsvYXM4OWlqZCYq

Comment: As you can see, all the special characters are removed :-D

Comment: And you can use base64_decode on the GET data before decrypting with codeignighter.

Comment: For now, I'll do this.  I think a redesign, or a random ID like newbie suggested will be a better idea in the long run.

Comment: Can i pass encrypted data through url?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe passing the cryped data through `urlencode()` would fix this? After you do that, you would have to intercept the data before CodeIgniter does, and run `urldecode()` on it.

Just a quick idea, so good luck!

Comment: Wouldn't that bloat the URL? Well, just a little bit, so it would propably be acceptable.

Comment: What's wrong with bloating? Stack Overflow bloats quite well... It shouldn't bloat much, as in might increase the length by ~5 chars.

Comment: I tried this, but a urlencodeed plus sign in a URL is still interpreted as a space, and a urlencoded slash is still a slash.

Answer (score 0):

Look for some characters that the encryption doesn't use and replace them as it fits. When using urls, undo it.

Comment: I was actually thinking of this.  Or rather, encrypting it again.  Every time I encrypt the ID, it's different.