# how to encrypt url parameters in codeigniter without disallowed characters?

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, encryption

i want to encrypt our url parameters on one page and decrypt on other page for security reason. when i try this then disallowed character error occurs. also i do not want to set $config['permitted_uri_chars']. according to this.

please give me solution that i can able to encrypt parameters with url like-

```
wwww.domain.com/controller_name/method_name/parameter1/parameter2
```

and i am using like for encrypt url-

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('C_Name/M_Name/'.$this->encrypt->encode($id)); ?>">Link</a>
```

and i am using like for decrypt url-

```
echo $this->encrypt->decode($id)
```

other issue is that its value is being changed randomly.

Please make me understand that how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: why nobody is not doing answer for this.

Comment: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/encryption.html

didn't it help you??

Comment: what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4347864/encrypted-data-in-urls

Comment: possible duplicate of [Encrypt IDs in URL variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4480908/encrypt-ids-in-url-variables)

Answer (score 5):

**STEP 1:**
Please create a helper function in helper folder

```
function encode_url($string, $key="", $url_safe=TRUE)
{
    if($key==null || $key=="")
    {
        $key="tyz_mydefaulturlencryption";
    }
      $CI =& get_instance();
    $ret = $CI->encrypt->encode($string, $key);

    if ($url_safe)
    {
        $ret = strtr(
                $ret,
                array(
                    '+' => '.',
                    '=' => '-',
                    '/' => '~'
                )
            );
    }

    return $ret;
}
  function decode_url($string, $key="")
{
     if($key==null || $key=="")
    {
        $key="tyz_mydefaulturlencryption";
    }
        $CI =& get_instance();
    $string = strtr(
            $string,
            array(
                '.' => '+',
                '-' => '=',
                '~' => '/'
            )
        );

    return $CI->encrypt->decode($string, $key);
}
```

**STEP 2:**  Assign this file in autoload file

`$autoload['helper'] = array('url','form','url_encryption_helper');`

**STEP 3:**
Call function `encode_url` in controller, model, view for encryption

```
   $rr="rahul K A";
   $a= encode_url($rr);
```

Comment: k a helped a lot thanks **developers always be a developers**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a querystring:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('C_Name/M_Name/?id='.$this->encrypt->encode($id)); ?>">Link</a>
```

In a query string, you can use anything