# codeigniter how can i encrypt and decrepit URL's and use form validation on them

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-rewriting, url-encoding

I will be emailing users a link where they can confirm a transaction in the email. I won’t be using a form in the email as it is not supported by all email clients.

So my URL will look something like:

example.com?userId=12&transId=23

I believe its bad practice sending out URL’s in this format so I would like to use encryption so it looks something like:

example.com?request=12s12ss1s2s12s12ndnjdss2

I can do this in normal PHP but after i have the values back how do I decrypt them and then pass them to the codeigniter form validation object

Comment: You should check this answer and always do search on google first. [Codeigniter encrypt url](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28274295/4388034)

Comment: @Arsh Singh `encrypt` assumes you need a secret to `decrypt`. The code your refer to is `obfuscate`, where you need an algorithm (not a secret) to reverse. See https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding-encryption-hashing-obfuscation/

Comment: @ffmisingh For security: be shure to `encrypt` with a secret key and then decrypt with that key instead of using obfuscation. https://danielmiessler.com/study/encoding-encryption-hashing-obfuscation/